# Absolute positioned ul stratch parent div

Tags: html, css

I look at example of dropdown menu [here](http://vremenno.net/examples/css-drop-down-menu/). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cnBzj/) is simplified jsfiddle example. I want to build my own styled  HTML element base on it. All it's ok. But in my implementation I need to wrap `<ul class="dropdown">...</ul>` with div styled with the CSS like this:

```
border: 2px solid green;
overflow: auto;
```

And in this case the ul with submenu stratch this div (as I understand) and that's why the scrollbars appeared. Here is [simplified jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/73Kbz/1/).

But if use the following css for outer div - all is ok:

```
border: 2px solid green;
height: 35px;
```

[Here is jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ESsfr/1/).

Could you help me to understand - why I have problems with **"overflow:auto"** case?

TIA!

Comment: you should use overflow:visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to give the container an overflow that is not visible, since that will hide your drop-down. Further, there's a lot of floating going on, that can now be `inline-block` with IE8+ support.

I forked your Jsfiddle and applied the CSS fixes at the bottom of the CSS Section. Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/VFZRB/

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `<ul>` within the `<ul>` (the submenu) `ul.dropdown ul` has style `visibility:hidden` if you removed that rule and add `display:none` - you won't see the scroll bars because, `visibility:hidden` preserves the width and height of the element and hides the element, while `display:none` is like removing the element from DOM. Hope this helped you

Comment: Yes, you are right - it removes scrollbars, but submenu don't shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
#killer{
border: 2px solid red;
overflow: visible;
}

<div id="killer">
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="./" class="dir">Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/js/">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="/photoshop/">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="/design/">Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="/misc/">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>​
```